# Java hashset constructor inline

Tags: java, owl

I have this piece of code:

```
        manager.addAxiom(
            ontology,factory.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(
                    factory.getOWLClass("CCC", prefix ),
                    factory.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(
                            Arrays.asList(
                                    factory.getOWLObjectComplementOf(
                                            factory.getOWLClass("AAA", prefix )),
                                    factory.getOWLClass("AAA", prefix )) )))  ;
```

As you can see I'm using Arrays.asList to represent a list of OWLClassExpressions.
This worked for OWLAPI 5, but now I have to do the same for OWLAPI4 which doesn't support List, but only Set.
How can I convert this code, which means using the inline constructor for Set class?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use

```
manager.addAxiom(
            ontology,factory.getOWLSubClassOfAxiom(
                    factory.getOWLClass("CCC", prefix ),
                    factory.getOWLObjectIntersectionOf(
                            new HashSet<T> (Arrays.asList(
                                    factory.getOWLObjectComplementOf(
                                            factory.getOWLClass("AAA", prefix )),
                                    factory.getOWLClass("AAA", prefix )) ))))  ;
```

where `T` is the type of the array elements (e.g. `OWLClassExpression`).